# Isabelle : proof using metis causes infinite loop

Tags: infinite-loop, isabelle, proof

I want to prove Lemma 1 and 2 and Lemma 21 is one of the subgoals for Lemma 2. However while proving Lemma 2 it hangs at apply (metis step) and I believe there's no other way to prove it. Are there any ways to stop this infinite loop from occuring? Thanks in advance.

```
inductive star :: "('a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool" for r where 
refl: "star r x x"|
step: "r x y ⟹star r y z⟹star r x z"


inductive star' ::"('a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"for r where 
refl' : "star' r x x" |
step' : "star' r x y ⟹ r y z ⟹ star' r x z"

lemma 21  : "r x y ⟹
       star r y z ⟹
       star' r y z ⟹
       star' r x z"
  apply (metis step)

lemma 1 : "star' r x y ⟹ star r x y"
  apply (induction rule : star'.induct)                
   apply (metis refl)
   done

lemma 2 : "star r x y ⟹ star' r x y"
  apply (induction  rule: star.induct)
  apply (metis refl')
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are referring to an exercise from [0]. I will refrain from posting a complete answer out of fear that this is a homework problem. However, I will give a tip. There is a redundant assumption in lemma 21. Once you remove this assumption, the lemma becomes easier to prove (as stated, using an `apply`-style script, and very standard textbook techniques). However, most likely, `metis` alone will not be enough.

If the worst comes to worst, you may also get an idea about how to prove this from the theory [Transitive_Closure.thy](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/Transitive_Closure.html) in Main. However, I would like to emphasize that the proof is very simple, so this should not be necessary.

[0] Nipkow T, Klein G. Concrete Semantics with Isabelle/HOL. Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag; 2017.

Comment: I looked up about redundant assumption but I couldn't understand it. Does the redundant assumption refer to ```star r y z```because it appears in both Lemma 2 and Lemma 21? Or does it refer to ```star r x y ⟹ star' r x y```?

Comment: The redundant assumption is, indeed, `star r y z` (I am not certain what is meant by `star r x y ⟹ star' r x y`, as there is no such assumption in the statement of the lemma `21`). Also, a further tip copied from the statement of the exercise: "note that rule induction fails if the assumption about the inductive predicate is not the first assumption."